# Android recycler view empty fields in header=(

Tags: android, header, android-recyclerview

First of all I want say sorry for my mistakes in English. I have a fragment with recycler view, where I have fields of form for creating ad. In recycler view I make the holder(header) with fields(title,price,description,type etc).; holder with items(photos), and holder (footer) with button "create Ad".

```
public class AddRemoveNumberedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements OnPhotoClickListener, OnDeleteButtonClickListener, View.OnClickListener, OnActivatePhoneListener, OnLoadPhoneNumbersListener, OnAllDataCollected {

private static final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 1;
private static final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ADD = 2;
private static final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER = 3;

private ArrayList<String> photoUrls;
private ArrayList<City> cities;
private PhoneNumbers phoneNumbers;
private NewPhotoViewHolder holder;
private CreateDeclarationFormHolder holderForm ;
private boolean isEdit;
private OnPhotoItemClickListener photoItemListener;
private OnActivatePhoneListener activateListener;
private OnLoadPhoneNumbersListener loadPhoneNumbersListener;
private SubcategoryBody subcategoryBody;
private OnDelarationReadyForSendListener declarationReadyListener;

    public boolean isHeader(int position){
        return position == 0;
    }

    public boolean isFooter(int position){
        return position == getItemCount()-1;
    }

    private boolean isAddButton(int position){return position == getItemCount() - 1 - 1/*footer*/;}

    //region Constructor
    public AddRemoveNumberedAdapter(SubcategoryBody subcategoryBody) {
        photoUrls = new ArrayList<>();
        cities = new ArrayList<>();
        this.subcategoryBody = subcategoryBody;
    }
    //endregion

    //region Adapter methods
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch (viewType){
            default:
            case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER:
                holderForm = new CreateDeclarationFormHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_declaration_form_header,parent,false));
                holderForm.setSubcategory(subcategoryBody);
                return holderForm;
            case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ADD:
            case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM:
                LayoutInflater inflaterItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                View itemView = inflaterItem.inflate(R.layout.item_photo_list,parent,false);
                holder = new NewPhotoViewHolder(itemView);
                return holder;
            case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER:
                return new SendDeclarationHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_send_declaration_footer,parent,false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)){
            case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER:
                ((CreateDeclarationFormHolder)holder).setCitiesList(cities);
                ((CreateDeclarationFormHolder)holder).setActivateListener(this);
                ((CreateDeclarationFormHolder)holder).setSpinnerPhoneNumbersList(phoneNumbers);
                ((CreateDeclarationFormHolder)holder).setLoadNumbersListener(this);
                ((CreateDeclarationFormHolder)holder).setLayoutVisibility(visibility,smsCount);

                break;
            case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER:
                ((SendDeclarationHolder)holder).sendDeclaration.setOnClickListener(this);
                break;
            case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM:
                ((NewPhotoViewHolder)holder).setOnDeleteButtonListener(this);
                Log.e("BIND HOLDER","PHOTO_URL "+ getPhotoUrl(position));
                ((NewPhotoViewHolder)holder).initWithPhotoPath(getPhotoUrl(position),isEdit);
                break;
            case ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ADD:
                ((NewPhotoViewHolder)holder).setOnPhotoClickListener(this);
                ((NewPhotoViewHolder)holder).initWithPhotoPath(null,isEdit);

                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(isHeader(position))return ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER;
        else if(isFooter(position))return ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER;
        else if(isAddButton(position))return ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ADD;
        else return ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(photoUrls!=null)
            return 1 /*header*/+ photoUrls.size() + 1/*add_item*/ + 1/*footer*/;
        else return 1 /*header*/+ 0/*photos*/ + 1/*add_item*/ + 1/*footer*/;
    }

    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(holderForm != null) {
        holderForm.setDataCollectedListener(this);
        holderForm.createDeclaration();
    }
}
```

when I click the button create(in footer holder) I call method createDeclaration() in my header. In this method I collect all data from my fields (EditTexts, Spinners,CheckBoxes,RadioButtons) and after create the class FormOfDeclaration(in my case in code i called that class CreateDeclarationFormHolder) where I save all of that fields.After I return this class to my fragment and in fragment I make pull request to server for creating Ad uses Retrofit 2.Method createDeclaration in holder(header) will be below:

```
 @Override
public void createDeclaration() {
    link = etLink.getText().toString();
    validData = new ValidateFormData(null,null,link);
    String phone = "";
    if(phoneNumbersModel != null && phoneNumbersModel.getList()!=null && phoneNumbersModel.getList().size()!=0) {
        phone =phoneNumbersModel.getList().get(spinnerPhoneNumbers.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1).getPhone();
        phoneId = getPhoneId(phoneNumbersModel.getList().get(spinnerPhoneNumbers.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1).getPhone());
    }else phoneId = "";

    int isdeliv = cbIsDelivery.isChecked() ? 1 : 0;
    int isfear = cbIsFear.isChecked() ? 1 : 0;
    int suggest_Price = cbSuggestPrice.isChecked() ? 1 : 0;
    String uniqId = getUniqId();
    String city = getSelectedCity();
    int typeOfDeclaration = spinnerType.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String title = etTitleOfDeclaration.getText().toString();
    String description = etDescription.getText().toString();
    String skype = etSkype.getText().toString();
    String price = etPrice.getText().toString();

    Log.i("CREATE","city: "+city+ " title: " + title + " description: " + description);

    //собираем данные из всех полей для создания объекта бланка на отправку объявления на сервер в зависимости от категории в которой находится пользователь
    CheckBox checkBox;
    int  size;
    String dataId ="";
    ArrayList<String> data = null;
    String spinnersIdModelORTypeRadioButton = "";
    String spinnerModelORTypeRadioButton = "";
    String spinnersIdTypeORManufacture = "";
    String spinnerTypeORManufacture = "";

    if(subcategoryBody.getParams()!= null && subcategoryBody.getParams().size()!= 0){
        for(int i = 0; i< subcategoryBody.getParams().size();i++){
            switch (subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getSettings().getT()){
                case  CHECK_BOX :
                    Log.i("CREATE DECLARATION","CHECK BOX ID:"+ String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getSettings().getId()));
                    size = subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().size();
                    dataId = String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getSettings().getId());
                    data = new ArrayList<>();
                    data.clear();
                    for(int j = 0 ;j < size;j++){
                        checkBox = (CheckBox)layout.findViewById(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(j).getId());
                        if(checkBox.isChecked())
                            data.add(String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(j).getId()));
                    }
                    break;
                case SPINNER:
                    Log.i("CREATE DECLARATION","SPINNER");
                    spinnersIdTypeORManufacture = String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getSettings().getId());
                    Log.i("CREATE DECLARATION","SPINNER + ID: "+ String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getSettings().getId()));
                    int selectedItemPosition = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    Log.i("CREATE DECLARATION","SPINNERS params: "+ "params size :"+ String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().size())+" i= "+String.valueOf(i)
                    +" values size of i: "+String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().size())+" selected position: "+selectedItemPosition);
                    spinnerTypeORManufacture = String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(selectedItemPosition - 1).getId());
                    if(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues()!= null && subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(selectedItemPosition - 1)!=null
                            && subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(selectedItemPosition - 1 ).getParameters()!=null &&
                            subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(selectedItemPosition - 1 ).getParameters().size() != 0) {
                        int selectedItemPositionOfModel = spinnerModel.getSelectedItemPosition();
                        int sizeExtraParameters = subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(selectedItemPosition-1).getParameters().size();
                        for(int j=0; j< sizeExtraParameters;j++) {
                            spinnersIdModelORTypeRadioButton = String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(selectedItemPosition - 1).getParameters().get(0).getSettings().getId());
                            spinnerModelORTypeRadioButton = String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(selectedItemPosition - 1).
                                    getParameters().get(j).getValues().get(selectedItemPositionOfModel-1).getId());
                        }
                        }
                    break;
                case RADIO_BUTTON:
                    spinnersIdModelORTypeRadioButton = String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getSettings().getId());
                    RadioButton rButton;
                    for (int j = 0;j < subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().size();j++) {
                        rButton = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(j).getId());
                        if(rButton.isChecked())
                            spinnerModelORTypeRadioButton = String.valueOf(subcategoryBody.getParams().get(i).getValues().get(j).getId());
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        DeclarationFormForSending formAntennaUKV = new DeclarationFormForSending(city,typeOfDeclaration,title,
                description,link,phoneId,phone,skype,price,isdeliv,isfear,suggest_Price,uniqId,
                subcategoryBody.getId(),spinnersIdTypeORManufacture,spinnerTypeORManufacture,spinnersIdModelORTypeRadioButton,spinnerModelORTypeRadioButton,dataId,data);
        Log.i("FORM  in ANTENNA_UKV",formAntennaUKV.toString());
        dataCollectedListener.allDataSending(formAntennaUKV);
    }
}
```

when I make Ad in first time i don't have problem code works good, but if after I go to another fragment or activity for example it's can be my menu or another part of application and after I am returning again to fragment "Creating Ad" and I trying to create new Ad with new data in fields my application works not bad and it trying to create this Ad but all my fields in second time stay empty!!!!!!! Why it happens?? =(